# The contrapositive of "if $x$ is even and $x$ is greater than $2$, then there exist prime numbers $p$ and $q$ such that $x = p + q$"

Tags: prime-numbers, proof-writing

Proposition: If $x$ is even and $x$ is greater than $2$, then there exist prime numbers $p$ and $q$
such that $x = p + q$.

Contrapositive: If for all prime numbers $p$ or $q$, $x$ does not equal $p + q$, then $x$ is odd or $x$ is less than or equal to $2$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your contrapositive is pretty much correct. All I would do is change the word "or" to "and":

> **Contrapositive:** If for all prime numbers $p$ $\color{red}{\text{and}}$ $q$ we have that $x \neq p + q$, then $x$ is odd or $x \leq 2$.

Comment: how come the or doesn't get negated?

Comment: When we say: "there exist prime numbers $p$ and $q$ such that...", it is equivalent to saying: "there exists a prime number $p$ and there exists a prime number $q$ such that...". So we're not really applying DeMorgan's Law; we're just flipping two existential quantifiers into universal quantifiers.